# How to add id to array in redux store?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have the following reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    items: [],
    cartOpen: false,
    total: 0
}

const Cart = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':
           return [...state.items,action.payload]

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Trying to dispatch an action like this:

```
 store.dispatch({type: 'ADD_TO_CART', payload: 22});
```

How can I push the payload which is an id to the items array?

Answer (score 0):

your reducer returns an array not an object to return an object without mutating the state use `Object.assign` or the `spread operator ...`
your code should look like this .

```
const initialState = {
    items: [],
    cartOpen: false,
    total: 0
}

const Cart = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':
           return Object.assign({} , state, {
              items : [...state.items,action.payload]
           })

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

make sure to use a pollyfill if your target browser doesn't support Object.assign or you could use the spread operator which I think doesn't require a pollyfill

```
const initialState = {
  items: [],
  cartOpen: false,
  total: 0
}

const Cart = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TO_CART':
     return { ...state, {
        items : [...state.items , action.payload]
     })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: The object.assign snippet works for me but not the spread one?

Comment: No, you should not return an array directly.  Use `return { ...state, items: [...state.items,action.payload] }`. @aeid you added a level (typo) more in your example.

Comment: That returns an error: index.js:9 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./cart"(…). cart.js contains the cartreducer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `immutability-helper` library to make changes to your state. One added advantage to it is that it will make it easy for you to make changes to the deeply nested object in your state easily

```
import update from 'immutability-helper'; 
const initialState = {
    items: [],
    cartOpen: false,
    total: 0
}

const Cart = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':
           return update(state, {
               items: {
                  $push: action.payload
               }
           })

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

[Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html)